# Отзывы о приложениях

Tags: android, java

Приветствую Всех!

Заинтересовала функция, реализованная в iOS. Это оставлять оценку (отзыв) о приложении, не заходя в App Store. Есть ли такое в Google Play (ex. Android Market), api или документации?
Куда копать? Подскажите.

Comment: Не пишите JAVA - это выглядит безграмотно! Надо писать Java

Answer (score 2):

То, что есть в iOS, не нужно перетаскивать в андроид. Здесь немного другая философия. 
В андоиде, если нужно к примеру добавить расшаривание, то программист не делает свое меню, в которое добавляет только свои сервисы. Он вызывает стандартное меню, к которому пользователь готов. Более того, у пользователя не нужно спрашивать пароли/доступы к приложению. На iOS в каждом приложении свой способ.

Почему так сделано? причина проста - так легче обеспечить безопасность и надежность. Одно приложение запрашивает, что оно хочет сделать, а второе, которое знает как это сделать, делает.

Но если сильно хочется и на карму наплевать, то можно сделать. Для маркета есть неофициальное [API](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/). Оно конечно скудное, но с него можно начать исследования. Как получить комментарии пользователей и скриншоты приложения там точно есть.

Но предлагать пользователю голосовать в наглую - очень плохо. А голосовать за него без его же ведома - ещё хуже. С большой вероятностью такое приложения выбросят с маркета.

Просто в окошке about поставьте ссылку на маркет и это будет правильно и красиво.